# A custom sorter for ListView in Yii2

Tags: yii2

Standard ListView widget automatically generates a kind of sorter by having the `{sorter}` section in its `$layout` property. However, I need a more sophisticated sorter with a custom template for my product list.

[image: sorter template]

Essentially I need to be able to:

1. Sort the list by several fields (popularity, newness, price, etc.)
2. Select how many entries per page to show (12, 50, 100)
3. Switch between two different view templates (more/less product information)

At this point I am trying to understand if I need to create a class descendant from `ListView` or I can configure the properties of the existing classes.

What is the best practice for implementing something like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1)** You can configure `sorter` like this:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'layout' => "{sorter}\n{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}", // Add sorter to layout because it's turned off by default
    'sorter' => [
        // ...
    ],
]) ?>
```

See available properties in official documentation to [yii\widgets\LinkSorter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-linksorter.html).

But there is no options for styling, so you need another soultion (by default the sorter is just `ul`).

You have two options here.

You can create custom class that extends from `yii\widgets\LinkSorter` and override `renderSortLinks()` method which is responsible for rendering html.

Then replace default `sorter` in your `ListView`:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'sorter' => [
        'class' => CustomLinkSorter::className(),
    ],
]) ?>
```

But I recommend using another method. Don't include the `{sorter}` in `layout`, and just create your own custom sorter that fit your needs. Put in inside common form and give the name `sort` to select. You are still can configure attributes list and other options in config to sorter.

Also you need give values to select options like this:
`popularity` - order by popularity (asc),
`-popularity` - order by popularity (desc).

**2)** As I remember Yii 2 does not have built-in options to generate such select. You should do this by yourself. Create the select box, give it the name `per-page` in common form (this is default name for limiting amount of records on one page). The names and values of select correspond necessary count.

At first you need override default values of [Pagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html) in your `dataProvider` before passing it to `ListView`:

```
$dataProvider->pagination = [
    'defaultPageSize' => 12,
    'pageSizeLimit' => [12, 100],
],
```

Then just pass it to `ListView`:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]) ?>
```

Also check this [extension](https://github.com/nterms/yii2-pagesize-widget), maybe you found it useful.

**3)** It can be solved like this. Because there is only two templates, you can add to your form parameter called something like `advanced-view`. So the basic template appears when this parameter is not set or equals `0`, and the advanced template corresponds the value `1`.

In `ListView` you can switch them depending on the value / existence of this GET parameter:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'itemView' => Yii::$app->request->get('advanced-view') ? '_advanced-view' : '_basic-view',
]) ?>
```